Redundancy in the definition of uniform spaces
Let me paraphrase Wikipedia's definition of uniform spaces:

Definition A. A set $X$ endowed with a nonempty collection $\Phi$ of subsets of $X \times X$ is a uniform space if the following conditions are satisfied:

For every $U \in \Phi$, the diagonal $\Delta \subset X \times X$ is a subset of $U$.
For every $U \in \Phi$, every subset $V$ of $X \times X$ that contains $U$ is a member of $\Phi$ as well.
For every $U, V \in \Phi$, $U \cap V$ is a member of $\Phi$ as well.
For every $U \in \Phi$, there exists $V \in \Phi$ such that $V' = \{(x, z) \in X \times X : \exists y \in X \; (x, y) \in V \land (y, z) \in V\}$ is a subset of $U$.
For every $U \in \Phi$, $U^{-1} = \{(y, x) \in X \times X : (x, y) \in U\}$ is a member of $\Phi$ as well.

Each member of $\Phi$ is called an entourage.

To me, this definition seemed to have quite a few redundancies. Formally, I wanted a simpler definition of uniform spaces that retains the notion of uniform continuity, which is defined as follows:

Let $(X, \Phi)$ and $(Y, \Psi)$ be uniform spaces. A function $f : X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous if, for every entourage $V \in \Psi$, there exists an entourage $U \in \Phi$ such that, for every $(x, y) \in U$, $(f(x), f(y)) \in V$ holds.

So here is my version of the definition of uniform spaces:

Definition B. A set $X$ endowed with a nonempty collection $\Phi$ of subsets of $X \times X$ is a uniform space if the following conditions are satisfied:

For every $U \in \Phi$, the diagonal $\Delta \subset X \times X$ is a subset of $U$.
For every $U \in \Phi$, $U = U^{-1}$ holds, where $U^{-1} = \{(y, x) \in X \times X : (x, y) \in U\}$.
For every $U \in \Phi$, there exists $V \in \Phi$ such that, for every $x, y, z \in X$ satisfying $(x,y), (y,z) \in V$, $(x,z) \in U$ holds.


Let me prove that the uniform continuity followed from Definition A coincides to that from Definition B. Here's the proof:

Let $(X, \Phi)$ and $(Y, \Psi)$ be uniform spaces judged by Definition A. It is possible to transform $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ to $\Phi'$ and $\Psi'$ respectively, where $\Phi'$ and $\Psi'$ agree with Definition B.
Formally, a subset $U'$ of $X \times X$ shall be a member of $\Phi'$ if and only if:

$U' \in \Phi$, and
$U' = U'^{-1}$.

Note that $\Phi' \subset \Phi$. It's clear that $\Phi'$ satisfies (B.1) and (B.2). To prove that $\Phi'$ satisfies (B.3), for given $U' \in \Phi'$, pick a $V \in \Phi$ owing to (A.4), and give $V' = V \cap V^{-1}$, which is in both $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$. Construct $\Psi'$ likewise.
Let $f : X \to Y$ be a uniformly continuous function, judged by Definition A. For every $V' \in \Psi'$, let $V' = V$. By (B.1), it's clear that $V \in \Psi$. Now there exists $U \in \Phi$ such that, for every $(x,x') \in U$, $(f(x),f(x')) \in V$ holds. Now let $U' = U \cap U^{-1}$. Since $U \cap U^{-1}$ is a member of $\Phi$ (by (A.3) and (A.5)), and since both $U$ and $U^{-1}$ contain the diagonal, and since $(x,y) \in U \cap U^{-1}$ if and only if $(y,x) \in U \cap U^{-1}$, both (B.1) and (B.2) are satisfied. that is, $U' \in \Phi'$. Since $U' \subset U$, for every $(x,x') \in U'$, $(f(x), f(x')) \in V' = V$ holds. We have just proved that $f$ is uniformly continuous judged by Definition B as well.


Conversely, let $(X,\Phi')$ and $(Y,\Psi')$ be uniform spaces judged by Definition B. It is possible to transform $\Phi'$ and $\Psi'$ to $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ respectively, where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ agree with Definition A.
Formally, a subset $U$ of $X \times X$ shall be a member of $\Phi$ if and only if there exists a finite collection $\{U'_1, \cdots, U'_n\}$ of members of $\Phi'$ such that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n U'_k$ is a subset of $U$.
Again, note that $\Phi' \subset \Phi$. It's clear that $\Phi$ satisfies all of (A.1), (A.2), (A.3), (A.4), and (A.5). Construct $\Psi$ likewise.
Let $f : X \to Y$ be a uniformly continuous function, judged by Definition B. For every $V \in \Psi$, let $\{V'_1, \cdots, V'_n\}$ be a finite collection of member of $\Psi'$ such that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n V'_k$ is a subset of $V$. For each $k \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, let $U'_k$ be a member of $\Phi'$ such that, for every $(x,x') \in U'_k$, $(f(x),f(x')) \in V'_k$ holds. Now let $U = \bigcap_{k=1}^n U'_k$. Then for every $(x,x') \in U$, $(f(x),f(x')) \in V'_k$ holds for every $k \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$. Then $(f(x),f(x')) \in \bigcap_{k=1}^n V'_k \subset V$. We have just proved that $f$ is uniformly continuous judged by Definition A as well.

Is my proof correct? If so, why did the definition of uniform spaces come up with such redundancies from the first place?

No. If you take $\Phi = \{\Delta\}$, it satisfies Definition B. However, it is not a uniformity.

I mean... Though Definition A and Definition B do not coincide by themselves, the uniform continuity they specify still coincide. Your "counterexample" declares a discrete space.
